# Displaying comma-separated data stored in a .txt file

Tags: java, android, csv, import-from-csv

I am currently building an app which will be used to time a race.

All the times are saved in a .txt file in this format.

```
STARTOFEVENT,20/11/2011 11:04:58
0,20/11/2011 11:05:14
1,20/11/2011 11:05:17,00:00:02
2,20/11/2011 11:05:19,00:00:04
3,20/11/2011 11:05:20,00:00:05
4,20/11/2011 11:05:21,00:00:06
5,20/11/2011 11:05:22,00:00:07
```

What I need help with is displaying the position number (column 1) and finish time (column 3) in a textView / editText as the results come in.

I have tried to a bit of code for parsing CSV files but with no luck.

Comment: Have you never used the string `split(...)` method before?

Comment: no never heard off it. but will look it up thanks

Comment: See my answer for an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example of `split(...)`...

```
String csvRecord = "1,20/11/2011 11:05:17,00:00:02";
String[] csvFields = csvRecord.split(",");
```

Each part of the string `csvRecord` separated by a comma is allocated to an element of the `csvFields` array. The number of array elements is dependent on the number of csv fields and is handled by the `split(...)` method which dynamically creates the array with the correct number.

From the above, `csvFields[0]` will be `1` with `csvFields[1]` as `20/11/2011 11:05:17` and `csvFields[2]` will be `00:00:02`

Comment: Glad to help - be careful to check the size of the array though. For instance splitting this line `0,20/11/2011 11:05:14` will return an array with only 2 elements instead of 3. Sounds obvious but an easy mistake to make depending on how well-formed your source csv data is.